# Linked server error- The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, table

There is a view that is being called from Server A (SQL 2016) and this view needs to read data from Server B (SQL 2014). There is a linked server set up between these two servers and the connection works fine.

The login that is running the view on the solution/application side is experiencing this error:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked
> server "Server B" does not contain the table ""DB1"."dbo"."TBL1"". The
> table either does not exist or the current user does not have
> permissions on that table.'.

-The login has DBO permissions on both DB's in Server A +B.

-The login is listed as a login in the linked server Security page.

-I have explicitly granted select on all tables being accessed, and it did not help.

-I am able to select and read from all tables under Server Objects >Linked Server> Server B > Table> Select To

-When the login runs the view from SSMS, it works fine without any errors.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on why this error might be occurring and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you granted select permissions to the view too?

Comment: The user you are using is SQL or Domain user?

Comment: @McNets - Yes I have, I forgot to mention that in my post. Thank you

Comment: @Marcin- It is a Windows Domain acct

Comment: Are you query the view on Server A directly from that server or from remote server? Does the query that is used in view works when you execute it on Server A?  Have you validated the database name on server B? To make it working on linked server it should be like that: [ServerB].[DB1].[SCHEMA].[TBL1]

Comment: @Marcin- yes the queries work only when executing in SSMS from Server A. We have used the full qualified name. The issue is not querying from SQL. The issue happens when on the solution/app side. We even tried to give it temporary sysadmin permissions to just test and see if it executes w/o error, and it didnt help...

Comment: Ok, so the problem most probable is with the 'double hop' Have you tried to configure connection between Server A and B using SQL Login? Check also this link: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/a-brief-explanation-and-solution-for-the-double-hop-problem

Comment: Usually a double-hop fails with `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'`, but perhaps `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` has a login, but lacks permissions to the target table.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem (with HIVE server link ) , restarting HIVE server fixed it.